# How to recursively iterate through a txt or html file using functions and returning each individual character

Tags: python, loops, parsing, functional-programming, tokenize

I am trying to create an input stream for the tokenization stage of an HTML parser I am building. Here is some context:

> The input stream consists of the characters pushed into it as the input byte stream is decoded.

> Before the tokenization stage, the input stream must be preprocessed by normalizing newlines. Thus, newlines in HTML DOMs are represented by U+000A LF characters, and there are never any U+000D CR characters in the input to the tokenization stage.

> The next input character is the first character in the input stream that has not yet been consumed. Initially, the next input character is the first character in the input. The current input character is the last character to have been consumed.

My test.html file:

> < !DOCTYPE html > on line 0

> > < head >Hi< /head > on line 1

My code:

```
with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    file = [item.replace('\n', '\f') for item in file]
    file = [str(item) for item in file]

def input_stream():
    for line_no, line in enumerate(file):  # the whole line 
            eof_no = len(file[line_no]) - 1
            
            for char_no, char in enumerate(line):  # each character in that line
                    eof_no = len(file[line_no]) - 1
                    if char_no == eof_no:
                        eof = True
                        return eof
                    return char

def run():
    eof = False
    while eof == False:
            result = input_stream()
            if result == True:
                break
            else:
                return result
print(run())

def state_machine(input): #Output of run() is to be passed in here
    #Statements..
```

So far I believe I have managed to include everything apart from the recursive portion of it. I need to return one character at a time, pass it into the state_machine function for it to perform certain operations and eventually return token(s) - all until the end of the file.

I know that returning anything in a function will end/break out of any loops but I do not know how else to model it.

Recap:
The returning of result iteratively does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively? When you read the html file using open, you can read it line by line until there are no lines left and you don't have to check for the eof. That would be a lot easier in my opinion.

Comment: because I need to check each character individually against statements in the state_machine function

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user56700 I am building a tokenizer. Broadly speaking, this receives inputs, and after meeting a few conditions (if statements or whatever), a specific token(s) will be emitted/added to a token list. Later, this list of tokens will be used to make a DOM Tree.

Comment: @user56700 Pt.2 The tokenizer is a huge state machine. It starts in one state: the data state (treat the states like functions pythonically and as stepping stones conceptually). The initial state (like most) calls for a new input char, performs certain operations, indicating the next stage. So to move around states, input chars need to meet certain criteria. My struggle is with creating and automating the system/function that constantly feeds each step of the state machine. The ideas I have to implement it, require far too many parameters and global variables to be efficient and clean.